# XSLT: How to show count of pass fail test cases

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to show count of pass fail test cases as well... please see the output.... any help ?? below logic is working fine. THANKS to all..... My stylesheet is attached below

Input:

```
 <TESTSEQUENCE> 
          <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:38</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
          <TESTCASENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15 </TESTCASENAME> 
          <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME>  
          <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
          <RESULT>ABORTED</RESULT> 
          <FINISHTIME>1399039672</FINISHTIME> 
        </TESTSEQUENCE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE>.......</TESTSEQUENCE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE>.......</TESTSEQUENCE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE>.......</TESTSEQUENCE>
```

Stylesheet:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="TESTSEQUENCE">
        <testcase>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[not (self::TESTCASESTARTTIME or self::TESTCASENAME or self::HTMLLOGFILENAME or self::RESULT)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each> 
            <xsl:attribute name="time">
                <xsl:value-of select="TESTCASESTARTTIME"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="TESTCASENAME"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="url">
                <xsl:value-of select="HTMLLOGFILENAME"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="status">
                <xsl:value-of select="RESULT"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </testcase>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output::

```
 <testsuite  tests=5 passed=3 failed=2>
            <testcase time="2014-05-02 16:02:38" name="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15 " scriptfilename="mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.txt" status="PASSED" finishtime="1399039672">
            </testcase>
        <testcase status="PASSED"></testcase>
        <testcase status="PASSED"></testcase>
        <testcase status="failed"></testcase>
        <testcase status="failed"></testcase>
        </testsuite>
```

Comment: Please show a **valid** XML input (with a root element) AND with data that matches the requested output; I don't see PASSED or FAILED anywhere in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here. Given an input of:

```
<TESTSUITE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE> 
          <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:38</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
          <TESTCASENAME>A</TESTCASENAME> 
          <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME>  
          <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
          <RESULT>FAILED</RESULT> 
          <FINISHTIME>1399039672</FINISHTIME> 
    </TESTSEQUENCE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE> 
          <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:39</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
          <TESTCASENAME>B</TESTCASENAME> 
          <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME>  
          <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
          <RESULT>PASSED</RESULT> 
          <FINISHTIME>1399039682</FINISHTIME> 
    </TESTSEQUENCE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE> 
          <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:40</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
          <TESTCASENAME>C</TESTCASENAME> 
          <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME>  
          <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
          <RESULT>PASSED</RESULT> 
          <FINISHTIME>1399039692</FINISHTIME> 
    </TESTSEQUENCE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE> 
          <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:41</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
          <TESTCASENAME>D</TESTCASENAME> 
          <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME>  
          <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
          <RESULT>ABORTED</RESULT> 
          <FINISHTIME>1399039702</FINISHTIME> 
    </TESTSEQUENCE>
    <TESTSEQUENCE> 
          <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:42</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
          <TESTCASENAME>E</TESTCASENAME> 
          <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME>  
          <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
          <RESULT>PASSED</RESULT> 
          <FINISHTIME>1399039712</FINISHTIME> 
    </TESTSEQUENCE>
</TESTSUITE>
```

the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/TESTSUITE">
    <testsuite tests="{count(TESTSEQUENCE)}" passed="{count(TESTSEQUENCE[RESULT='PASSED'])}" failed="{count(TESTSEQUENCE[RESULT='FAILED'])}">
        <xsl:for-each select="TESTSEQUENCE">
            <testcase>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[not (self::TESTCASESTARTTIME or self::TESTCASENAME or self::HTMLLOGFILENAME or self::RESULT)]">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each> 
                <xsl:attribute name="time">
                    <xsl:value-of select="TESTCASESTARTTIME"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="TESTCASENAME"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="url">
                    <xsl:value-of select="HTMLLOGFILENAME"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="status">
                    <xsl:value-of select="RESULT"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </testcase>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </testsuite>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite tests="5" passed="3" failed="1">
   <testcase SCRIPTFILENAME="/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" FINISHTIME="1399039672" time="2014-05-02 16:02:38" name="A" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html" status="FAILED"/>
   <testcase SCRIPTFILENAME="/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" FINISHTIME="1399039682" time="2014-05-02 16:02:39" name="B" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html" status="PASSED"/>
   <testcase SCRIPTFILENAME="/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" FINISHTIME="1399039692" time="2014-05-02 16:02:40" name="C" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html" status="PASSED"/>
   <testcase SCRIPTFILENAME="/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" FINISHTIME="1399039702" time="2014-05-02 16:02:41" name="D" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html" status="ABORTED"/>
   <testcase SCRIPTFILENAME="/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" FINISHTIME="1399039712" time="2014-05-02 16:02:42" name="E" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html" status="PASSED"/>
</testsuite>
```